# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma de una aplicación OpenXava?

Tags: java, i18n, internacionalización, openxava

Quiero que mi aplicación OpenXava funcione con varios idiomas (inglés, japonés y español). ¿Cómo puedo establecer el idioma de mi aplicación a japonés, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Una aplicación OpenXava funciona por defecto con el idioma definido en el navegador del usuario como idioma principal. Es decir, si quieres ver tu aplicación OpenXava en japonés con Chrome, ve a la opción de Configuración, allí abre las opciones avanzadas y después abre la sección Idiomas. Mueve el japonés a la primera posición de la lista. De esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Firefox, Safari y Edge también ofrecen la posibilidad de establecer el idioma en las opciones. Después, recarga la página en tu navegador y tu aplicación aparecerá en japonés, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

OpenXava tiene la mayoría de las etiquetas de uso común traducidas a español, inglés, alemán, francés, chino, ruso, japonés, portugués, catalán, indonesio, italiano, polaco, servio y sueco, por lo que la mayoría de las etiquetas estarán en japonés automáticamente. Además puedes añadir nuevas traducciones para tus propios términos o añadir un nuevo idioma fácilmente. Echa un vistazo a la [documentación de OpenXava sobre internacionalización](https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/i18n_en.html).